# TypeError while unpacking train data loader in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a CNN model on an image dataset that has an extension `.npy`, but I get a TypeError in the train loop.

#### Imports

```py
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import tqdm
```

#### CNN model

```py
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*64*64, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 3)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
    
    def forward(self, image: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        image = self.pool(self.relu(self.conv1(image)))
        image = self.pool(self.relu(self.conv2(image)))
        image = self.pool(self.relu(self.conv3(image)))
        image = image.view(-1, 64*64*64)
        image = self.dropout(self.relu(self.fc1(image)))
        image = self.fc2(image)
        return image
```

#### Hyperparameters

```py
train_path = 'dataset/train'
val_path = 'dataset/val'
num_epochs = 11
num_classes = 3
batch_size = 64
learning_rate = 0.002
train_test_ratio = 0.9

device = torch.device('mps' if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

#### Loading train data

```py
import numpy as np

def npy_loader(path):
    sample = torch.from_numpy(np.load(path))
    return sample

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(), transforms.ToTensor()])
dataset = datasets.DatasetFolder(
    root=train_path,
    loader=npy_loader,
    extensions='.npy',
    transform=transform
)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

#### Training

```py
model = CNN()
model.to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
model.train()
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss = 0.0
    for data, target in tqdm(trainloader):
        data = data.to(device)
        target = target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item() * data.size(0)
    train_loss = train_loss/len(trainloader.dataset)
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1} \tTraining Loss: {train_loss:.6f}')
```

#### Error

`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` in line `for data, target in tqdm(trainloader):`

I tried coding `MyDataset` a custom Dataset class, but that did not solve my error.

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, np_file_paths, transform=None):
        self.files = np_file_paths
        self.transform = transform
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = np.load(self.files[index])
        x = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
        if self.transform is not None:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return x
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tqdm is both the name of the library and the name of the main class contained inside. You should simply change at the start of your file

```
import tqdm
```

to:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

This can be confusing for beginners but is often the case in Python for packages with one main class.

You should always try to reduce your buggy code to a minimal reproducible example before posting.